# Relation between using stratify and class weights for imbalanced classes

Tags: random-forest, multiclass-classification, class-imbalance, sampling

I'm working on a multi-class classification problem where the classes are imbalanced (70:25:5).

Train-Test Split

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, stratify=Y)
```

Random Forest Classifier

```
cls = {0:.9, 1:.09, 3:.01}
RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1, random_state=42, oob_score=True, class_weight=cls)
```

I do not see a change in the results after assigning class weights. Is there anything that I need to look into in particular here? Thanks in advance!